# Angular: get file length from file input

Tags: angularjs

I have input like this: `<input id="file" name="someFile" type="file" ng-model="userInfo.someFile" />` . How can I get file length in js code using Angular?
Something like this don't work:

```
var fileLen = $('#file').files[0].length;
if (fileLen == 0) {
  //some code
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly do you mean by file length?  I am assuming you are asking the number of files selected?  If not let me know and I can update the answer. But the below will show you how to get access to the $event object which has the file(s) properties.

html:

```
  <div>
     <input ng-change="add_files($event)" type="file" multiple>
  </div>
```

in your controller:

```
$scope.add_files = function($event){
  //this will give you the $event object details
  //from that object you should be able to determine file name(s) /  size(s)
  //I believe this will give you the file size
  console.log($event.files[0].size)
}
```

Comment: I ment the size of file :)

Comment: Need to check if (file size == 0) {isValid = false}

Comment: See updates.  I recommend console logging the $event object to confirm there is a file key.  That key should have a value which is an array of objects (each object referencing a specific file).  Those file objects should have a size key specifying file size.